# injectivity of a functions implies image commutes under intersections

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f: X \to Y $ be an injective function. Let $\{ A_i \}_{I \in I }$
> be a family of subsets of $X$. Prove carefully that
>
> $$ f \bigg( \bigcap A_i \bigg) = \bigcap f(A_i) $$

### Attempt:

if $y \in f( \bigcap A_i ) $, then there is some $x \in \bigcap A_i $ with $f(x) = y $. But as $\bigcap A_i \subset A_i$, then we see that we can find an $x \in A_i $ with $f(x) = y $ which precisely means that $y \in \bigcap f(A_i ) $

Conversely, if $y \in \bigcap f(A_i) $, then $y$ is in all of the $f(A_i)$ so there is some $x \in A_i $ so that $f(x) = y $. But, this $x$ lies in all of the $A_i$ so by definition $x \in \bigcap A_i $ and so $y \in f( \bigcap A_i ) $

Question: I haven't used the fact that $f$ is injective. I am afraid I may have a typo in my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second part:

For every $i\in I$ there is some $x_i\in A_i$  with $f(x_i)=y$.

Then the injectivity of $f$ tells us that these $x_i$ must coincide.

(In your attempt you abusively take that for granted).

So some $x$ exists with $x=x_i\in A_i$ for each $i$.

Evidently $x\in\bigcap A_i$ and consequently $y=f(x)\in f(\bigcap A_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

The converse lacks rigour. I would say it as follows:

Let $y \in \displaystyle\bigcap_i f(A_i)$ For each $i$, there is an $x_i\in A_i$ such that $y=f(x_i)$. As $f$ is injective, all these $x_i$ are  but one, which therefore lies in  $\displaystyle\bigcap_i  A_i$. Thus $y\in f\Bigl(\displaystyle\bigcap_i  A_i\Bigr)$.